# How to take random sample from a csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with 10 rows:

```
Text,Class
text0,class0
text1,class1
...
text9,class9
```

I am classifying the text, and then comparing it to the correct class labeled in the csv file. I want to take a random sample of 4 pieces of text and their class from it. I have:

```
import random
textt=data['Text']
class_one=data['Class']
c=textt[0:]
random_sample=random.sample(c,4)
```

My classification then starts with:

```
for i in random_sample:
```

but when i calculate the accuracy of the classification, it calculates it for the entire dataset. How can I get it to only calculate the accuracy for just the sample of 4 pieces of data?

edit: 
for classification, i do:
    for i in textt:
        #classify text
results will look like:

```
choice 1
choice 2
choice 1
...
```

and this is compared to the correct class from the csv file:

```
choice 1
choice 2
choice 2
...
```

and accuracy will be calculated as 66.6% with:

```
for i in class_one:
    #if predicted_class= correct_class: 
    #accuracy=number_correct/total_number
```

I want to only do the classification on the random sample, so instead of classifying all 10 examples, it would only classify 4

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're doing any of the stuff you're talking about; without a [mcve] it's pretty hard to give you a concrete answer. But most likely, it's just a matter of calling `<something>(random_sample)` instead of `<something>(c)`, or similar.

Comment: Just use dataframe.sample(4) , refer the docs - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: I just added an edit, does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do it is use [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
print(df.sample(4)) #Number of items from axis to return. Cannot be used with frac. Default = 1 if frac = None.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the `pandas` solution is the right one for you. In case you want to split any CSV-file generically in python to a random shuffled 20%:80% training- and test-splits, you can use core python:

```
import random
x     = open("dataset.csv").readlines()
random.shuffle(x)
train = x[:int(total*0.8)]
test  = x[int(total*0.8):]
```

As it seems you are trying to evaluate some kind of classification (machine learning?) task, I would highly recommend looking up `scikit-learn`'s [`train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), as it can stratify for other variables and also works with pandas DataFrames.